# How to call a fragment layout from the FragmentActivity to avoid NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, oncreate

I am using action bar tabs with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. (3 tabs)
I have `onCreateOptions` menu set at the **MainActivity** that extends `FragmentActivity`.

This menu contains a save button that runs `saveData()` method on the **MainActivity**, which saves the data in the whole 3 fragments.

The problem is that when I first open the app and hit the save button, I get NPE when this method tries to save data on the 3rd fragment. I know that this is because `onCreateView()` method is not called yet, and when I switch tabs, the saveData() method works fine.

The question is, how can I avoid the NPE? or how can I call the layout of the 3rd fragment so that `saveData()` can access its views.

Comment: Post your existing code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the simplest way would be to just check your `Fragments` views for null inside your `saveData()` method. If it is necessery to save data from every fragment, you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) method on your `ViewPager` to force it to load all fragments at once.

Comment: Solved! setOffscreenPageLimit (int limit) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot check Fragment views for null because there are some variables that are set to zero unless the Fragment layout is loaded. This is due to the fact that I am calling loadData() when onActivityCreated() is initiated. Any other approaches are welcome!